# Element type is invalid - error in render, js and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in js and react mainly for this project and I am attempting to implement a forget/reset password form. I have a route for the main page and then the new route for resetting which is at: "/link/reset". The route takes me to the page, however, this error message pops up.

Not sure what is going on, any suggestions or guidance on how to solve this would be very appreciated.

The error message is:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ResetPassword`.

```js
Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:39
  36 |   }
  37 | });
  38 | 
> 39 | ReactDOM.render(
  40 |   <Provider store={store}>
  41 |    <Router>
  42 |      <App />
```

here is one of the resetpassword render methods, I have more than one but they all follow similar formats:

```js
  function renderRequestCodeForm() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSendCodeClick}>
        <FormGroup bsSize="large" controlId="email">
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={fields.email}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <LoaderButton
          block
          type="submit"
          bsSize="large"
          isLoading={isSendingCode}
          disabled={!validateCodeForm()}
        >
          Send Confirmation
        </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: What does the `ResetPassword` render method look like? It was supposed to display a string value but its getting something else.

Comment: How is `ResetPassword ` implemented, can you add that part?

Comment: @SebastianGbudje an example of the render method is above

Comment: It's still hard to see what the issue is without more code snippets are you exporting that `renderRequestCodeForm` component? Also how are you importing it for use?